# Trying to convert Javascript AES encryption to Python

Tags: javascript, python, encryption, aes

I'm trying to convert the following Javascript code to python:

```
cryptoJs.AES.encrypt("secrettext", cryptoJs.enc.Base64.parse("QWJjZGVmZ2hpamtsbW5vcA=="), { iv: cryptoJs.enc.Base64.parse("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==")}).ciphertext.toString(cryptoJs.enc.Base64)
```

I've been trying to figure out the python equivalent of the different parts (key and iv), but nothing is working. This is what I last tried but was given an error that my IV was the incorrect length:

```
key = b"QWJjZGVmZ2hpamtsbW5vcA=="
iv = b"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=="
text = b"secrettext"

base64_key = base64.b64encode(key)
base64_iv = base64.b64encode(iv)

padtext=pad(text,16,style='pkcs7')

encryptor = AES.new(base64_key, AES.MODE_CBC, base64_iv)
result = encryptor.encrypt(padtext)
print(binascii.hexlify(result))
```

Comment: As your key and iv in JS is already base64 encoded you should try to base64.b64decode the values as input for your encryption :-)

Comment: @MichaelFehr I thought the cryptoJs.enc.Base64.parse function encoded strings, you're saying it decodes? Thank you

Comment: Also, in the Python code the ciphertext must be Base64 and not hex encoded (i.e. replace `hexlify()` with `b64encode()`).

Comment: Thank you @Topaco it's working now.